# Python get dictionary of instance attributes but not methods

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

I am currently attempting to build a method within a class that can provide me the attributes of an instance.

The idea is to have a dictionary of a attributes of an instance which substitute any default class attributes.

The current method doing this is def printVars(object) but I am failing to remove the methods "props" and "printVars" even when using inspect or callable.

I assumed that methods and "__xxxx__" were not callable at all but inside this method they seem to be callable so this approach didnt work. Also the inspect is not detecting that either props or printVars are methods.

I want this dictionary to be returned so I can use it as input information for a module or another class. I do not want to create a child class from here since the variables need to be used for a different concept in telecom and they will be used for many concepts but for each I plan to either define a new class or a new module to which I can pass constructed dictionaries with new data.

Previous program was developed in matlab.

Any advice on how to remove methods from my dictionary?
Or maybe a more Pythonic approach to my approach?

```
import datetime
import math
import os
import random
import urllib2
import inspect

class GPS_Parameters(object):
   area_km=40*1609.344
   area_coverage=math.pow(area_km,2)
   area_miles=40
   bandwidth_for_positioning=4.5e6 #Bandwidth for location data
   bandwidth_spectrum_allocation=4.995e6
   cluster_nodes=1
   cyclic_prefix_size=2*161+1
   delay_spread=20e-6
   frame_type = 1 #Location, information and synchronization   
   hyperbolic_vector_size=64
   init_method='locus' #Choices available are 'random' and 'locus'
   noise_value=0 #Explicit noise variance to create a range error
   number_iterations = 8 #Number of times we iterate in hyperbolic 
                     #solution solver_number_solutions
   number_segments=0
   number_simulations=35 #Returns with new noise statistics and a new 
                     #fading channel, should choose new targe location
   number_targets = 1 #targets to be located
   number_symbols=1
   sampling_frequency=7.68e6 #Sampling frequency of multicarrier modulation
                         #(subcarrier space 15e3) 
   segment_size=0
   simulation_mode=None #Modes: AWGN_Fading_Interference, AWGN_Fading, AWGN
   snr_db=25
   snir_db=25
   subcarrier_bw=15e3   

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.number_sub_carriers=kwargs["number_sub_carriers"]
      self.reference_nodes=kwargs["reference_nodes"]
      self.rician_kdb=kwargs["rician_kdb"]
      self.simulation_mode=kwargs["simulation_mode"]
      self.snir_db=kwargs.get("snir_db")
      self.snr_db=kwargs.get("snr_db")
      self.total_cazac_bw=self.subcarrier_bw*self.number_sub_carriers

   def props(cls):
      return [i for i in cls.__dict__.keys() if i[:1] != '_']

   def printVars(object):
      for i in [v for v in dir(object) if v[:1] !='_']:
         if inspect.ismethod(i) !=True:
            print '\n%s:' % i
            exec('print object.%s\n\n') % i
            # Dictionary append should go here


if __name__ == "__main__":
   test1parameters={"simulation_mode":"AWGN", "snr_db":15,"rician_kdb":8,\
                "reference_nodes":7,"number_sub_carriers":128}
   gpstest1=GPS_Parameters(**test1parameters)
   gpstest1.printVars()
```

Comment: Your props(cls) and printVars(object) would conventionally (pythonically) be declared as props(self) and printVars(self) - i.e. they operate on an instance. It's confusing to use your declarations - they are non-pythonic.

Comment: But... I don't understand why anyone would want to do this. Why? What are you trying to achieve? What is the problem you are trying to solve? What can't you do any other way?

Comment: Hello, idea is to build a GPS system. Initially the system needs to have certain parameters. The idea is to have one class that has "default" class attributes which can be substituted by instance attributes provided by the user depending on its needs ex snr_db. Then all attributes needs to be stored in a dictionary which is what I am attempting on printVars. These key, values which have been stored in a dictionary will be them passed to either a module or another class (I havent decided the structure of my program yet)

Comment: Hi @barny could you advice

Answer (score 0):

In `printVars()` `dir(object)` returns a list of *strings* which are the names of the object's attributes. These strings are being passed to `inspect.ismethod()`.

`inspect.ismethod()` checks if its argument is an instance method. A string object is not an instance method, so it returns `False`. That's why the methods `printVars()` and `props()` are displayed by your code.

I don't what your code is trying to achieve, but maybe you can do something like this:

```
inspect.getmembers(gpstest1, lambda x: not callable(x))
```

or

```
inspect.getmembers(gpstest1, lambda x: not inspect.ismethod(x))
```

You could also access the instance's `__dict__` to see the instance variables:

```
>>> gpstest1.__dict__
{'total_cazac_bw': 1920000.0, 'rician_kdb': 8, 'simulation_mode': 'AWGN', 'number_sub_carriers': 128, 'snr_db': 15, 'snir_db': None, 'reference_nodes': 7}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your advice. The problem with using gpstest1.__dict__ is that I will only get the instance attributes only, also if I use "print inspect.getmembers(gpstest1, lambda x: not callable(x))" it will provide me the key, values of instance attributes and class attributes plus some other things that start with __ that I don't require. The idea is to have a method that returns instance attributes that have substituted class attributes along with the rest of the class attributes the user didnt specify in dictionary form. @mhawke